# How to debug source code that expects an input (with eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, input, program-entry-point

I try to debug a larger source code that expects an input in the main function. Otherwise it just prints the line:

```
"usage: Programm <example_input.xml>"
```

I don't know how to insert this input at the beginning of the debugging so that I can step through the whole code.
I'm using eclipse for the debugging. If it's not possible to dot his with eclipse I can switch to the gdb-debugger in the command line.

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the arguments in:

```
Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> Program Arguments
```